# Convention-based-Registration Extension for Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm trying to figure out what is is considered a good way of implementing this one.

```
public class UnityEx : UnityRegistry
{
    private static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: See worked example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168458/unity-autoregistration-convention-based-registration-unity/25654904#25654904.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AdvancedConfigurationEngineForUnity). It contains an enhanced configuration engine for Unity. It started as a port of the StructureMap configuration and brings support for conventions to Unity.